# javascript slider like "highstock slider"

Tags: jquery, javascript, highcharts

How can I get slider just like **highstock slider**

or

How can I customize highstock so that I can only use its slider no chart. I want to change page content like tables few charts on slider move.

Please refer the image to visualize the problem

On move or change of slider I need to change the complete page data like "table data and chart"

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like jquery-ui slider.

Comment: no I am looking for slider exactly same like "highstock slider"
My client send me this link [http://au.finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=ANZ.AX#symbol=ANZ.AX;range=1d] and asked me create only slider like "yahoo finance" in HTML

Comment: I'm not sure how it should look like, slider you mean scroll in a bottom or something other? 
Your example is similar with http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume

Comment: please refer the image for exact problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use http://jsfiddle.net/f7Y9p/

```
yAxis: {
            height: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            tickLength : 0,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }                   
        },
series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            lineWidth: 0,
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
```

empty chart with only navigator, then catch afterSetExtremes() (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) and if you get values, then set it in other charts by setExtreme() function http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes().